# Why won't my (thinking) sphinx restart?

Tags: sphinx, thinking-sphinx

```
$ RAILS_ENV=staging rake ts:start
Failed to start searchd daemon. Check /home/mysuser/public_html/site_folders/rails_apps/myuser/staging/current/log/searchd.log
```

Here's what that file says:

```
 17 [Thu Jun 12 23:54:05.854 2014] [ 3234] rotating finished
 18 [Thu Jun 12 23:59:19.998 2014] [ 3234] rotating indices (seamless=1)
 19 [Thu Jun 12 23:59:20.005 2014] [ 3234] rotating index 'user_core': success
 20 [Thu Jun 12 23:59:20.007 2014] [ 3234] rotating index 'pack_core': success
 21 [Thu Jun 12 23:59:20.009 2014] [ 3234] rotating index 'media_clip_core': success
 22 [Thu Jun 12 23:59:20.013 2014] [ 3234] rotating index 'lesson_core': success
 23 [Thu Jun 12 23:59:20.015 2014] [ 3234] rotating index 'instructor_core': success
 24 [Thu Jun 12 23:59:20.019 2014] [ 3234] rotating index 'collection_core': success
 25 [Thu Jun 12 23:59:20.019 2014] [ 3234] rotating finished
 26 [Fri Jun 13 00:02:39.730 2014] [ 3234] rotating indices (seamless=1)
 27 [Fri Jun 13 00:02:39.800 2014] [ 3234] rotating index 'user_core': success
 28 [Fri Jun 13 00:02:39.801 2014] [ 3234] rotating index 'pack_core': success
 29 [Fri Jun 13 00:02:39.803 2014] [ 3234] rotating index 'media_clip_core': success
 30 [Fri Jun 13 00:02:39.805 2014] [ 3234] rotating index 'lesson_core': success
 31 [Fri Jun 13 00:02:39.806 2014] [ 3234] rotating index 'instructor_core': success
 32 [Fri Jun 13 00:02:39.917 2014] [ 3234] rotating index 'collection_core': success
 33 [Fri Jun 13 00:02:39.917 2014] [ 3234] rotating finished
 34 [Fri Jun 13 00:24:53.066 2014] [ 3234] rotating indices (seamless=1)
 35 [Fri Jun 13 00:24:53.108 2014] [ 3234] rotating index 'user_core': success
 36 [Fri Jun 13 00:24:53.110 2014] [ 3234] rotating index 'pack_core': success
 37 [Fri Jun 13 00:24:53.111 2014] [ 3234] rotating index 'media_clip_core': success
 38 [Fri Jun 13 00:24:53.114 2014] [ 3234] rotating index 'lesson_core': success
 39 [Fri Jun 13 00:24:53.116 2014] [ 3234] rotating index 'instructor_core': success
 40 [Fri Jun 13 00:24:53.132 2014] [ 3234] rotating index 'collection_core': success
 41 [Fri Jun 13 00:24:53.132 2014] [ 3234] rotating finished
 42 [Fri Jun 13 00:26:07.920 2014] [ 3234] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
 43 [Fri Jun 13 00:26:07.921 2014] [ 3234] shutdown complete
 44 [Fri Jun 13 00:26:07.988 2014] [11281] accepting connections
 45 [Fri Jun 13 00:32:27.635 2014] [11281] rotating indices (seamless=1)
 46 [Fri Jun 13 00:32:27.656 2014] [11281] WARNING: rotating index 'user_core': cur to old rename failed: rename /home/myuser/public_html/site_folders/rails_apps/myuser/sphinx_i> 47 [Fri Jun 13 00:32:27.657 2014] [11281] WARNING: rotating index 'pack_core': cur to old rename failed: rename /home/myuser/public_html/site_folders/rails_apps/myuser/sphinx_i>
 48 [Fri Jun 13 00:32:27.658 2014] [11281] WARNING: rotating index 'media_clip_core': cur to old rename failed: rename /home/myuser/public_html/site_folders/rails_apps/myuser/sp> 49 [Fri Jun 13 00:32:27.660 2014] [11281] WARNING: rotating index 'lesson_core': cur to old rename failed: rename /home/myuser/public_html/site_folders/rails_apps/myuser/sphinx>
 50 [Fri Jun 13 00:32:27.661 2014] [11281] WARNING: rotating index 'instructor_core': cur to old rename failed: rename /home/myuser/public_html/site_folders/rails_apps/myuser/sp> 51 [Fri Jun 13 00:32:27.670 2014] [11281] WARNING: rotating index 'collection_core': cur to old rename failed: rename /home/myuser/public_html/site_folders/rails_apps/myuser/sp> 52 [Fri Jun 13 00:32:27.670 2014] [11281] rotating finished
 53 [Fri Jun 13 00:36:19.604 2014] [11281] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
 54 [Fri Jun 13 00:36:19.604 2014] [11281] shutdown complete
```

At the same time this happened (after reindexing), I noticed that my indexes were renamed with the word "new" in them:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser      64 Jun 13 00:31 collection_core.new.spa
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser    1508 Jun 13 00:31 collection_core.new.spd
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser     409 Jun 13 00:31 collection_core.new.sph
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser    1106 Jun 13 00:31 collection_core.new.spi
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser       0 Jun 13 00:31 collection_core.new.spm
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser    1601 Jun 13 00:31 collection_core.new.spp
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser    1056 Jun 13 00:32 dance_genre_core.new.spa
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser   59066 Jun 13 00:32 dance_genre_core.new.spd
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser     501 Jun 13 00:32 dance_genre_core.new.sph
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser   29076 Jun 13 00:32 dance_genre_core.new.spi
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser       0 Jun 13 00:32 dance_genre_core.new.spm
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser   64118 Jun 13 00:32 dance_genre_core.new.spp
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser    3588 Jun 13 00:32 instructor_core.new.spa
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser  214038 Jun 13 00:32 instructor_core.new.spd
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser     539 Jun 13 00:32 instructor_core.new.sph
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser   65537 Jun 13 00:32 instructor_core.new.spi
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser       0 Jun 13 00:32 instructor_core.new.spm
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser  220015 Jun 13 00:32 instructor_core.new.spp
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser   93264 Jun 13 00:32 lesson_core.new.spa
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser 1813151 Jun 13 00:32 lesson_core.new.spd
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser     524 Jun 13 00:32 lesson_core.new.sph
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser  106811 Jun 13 00:32 lesson_core.new.spi
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser       0 Jun 13 00:32 lesson_core.new.spm
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser 2175194 Jun 13 00:32 lesson_core.new.spp
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser     760 Jun 13 00:32 media_clip_core.new.spa
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser   14815 Jun 13 00:32 media_clip_core.new.spd
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser     478 Jun 13 00:32 media_clip_core.new.sph
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser    7188 Jun 13 00:32 media_clip_core.new.spi
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser       0 Jun 13 00:32 media_clip_core.new.spm
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser   16921 Jun 13 00:32 media_clip_core.new.spp
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser   13776 Jun 13 00:32 pack_core.new.spa
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser  247395 Jun 13 00:32 pack_core.new.spd
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser     499 Jun 13 00:32 pack_core.new.sph
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser   45122 Jun 13 00:32 pack_core.new.spi
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser       0 Jun 13 00:32 pack_core.new.spm
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser  279170 Jun 13 00:32 pack_core.new.spp
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser  232096 Jun 13 00:32 user_core.new.spa
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser  917713 Jun 13 00:32 user_core.new.spd
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser     384 Jun 13 00:32 user_core.new.sph
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser  400761 Jun 13 00:32 user_core.new.spi
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser       0 Jun 13 00:32 user_core.new.spm
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser  545756 Jun 13 00:32 user_core.new.spp
```

Answer (score 0):

give a try

```
rake ts:clear   
rake ts:index  
rake ts:start
```